# Creating one training/test set that works with regsubet and ridge/lasso regression

Tags: r, regression, training-data

I'm following Exercise 6.9 from this link: https://notendur.hi.is/map27/ISLR/ISLRChapter6.html

Specifically, the instructor creates the training and test datasets in this way:

```
set.seed(1)
trainRows = sample(dim(College)[1], ceiling(dim(College)[1]/2))
train = is.element(c(1:dim(College)[1]),trainRows)
test = !train
```

Now the "train" and "test" objects are logical operators. Now these training and test objects work for `lm`, `ridge` and `lasso`.

```
#Linear Regression
fit = lm(Apps~., data=College[train, ])
fit.pred = predict(fit, College[test, ])
mean((College[test, ][, "Apps"] - fit.pred)^2)
#Ridge Regression
trainMat = model.matrix(Apps~., data=College[train, ])
testMat = model.matrix(Apps~., data=College[test, ])
grid = 10 ^ seq(10, -10, length=100)
ridgeModel = cv.glmnet(trainMat, College[train, ][, "Apps"], alpha=0, 
lambda=grid)
optLambda = ridgeModel$lambda.min
optLambda
#Ridge MSE
ridgePred = predict(ridgeModel, newx=testMat, s=optLambda)
mean((College[test, ][, "Apps"] - ridgePred)^2)
#Lasso Model
lassoModel = cv.glmnet(trainMat, College[train, ][, "Apps"], alpha=1, 
lambda=grid)
optLambda = lassoModel$lambda.min
optLambda
#Test MSE - Lasso
lassoPred = predict(lassoModel, newx=testMat, s=optLambda)
mean((College[test, ][, "Apps"] - lassoPred)^2)
```

However when I attempt to use these objects with the `regsubsets` function, I get the following message:

`regfit.full=regsubsets(Apps ~ ., data = train)`

`Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument`

However, when I create a training/test object in the following way (which does *not* work for the `ridge` and `lasso` regressions using the `glmnet` package), it worked with `regsubset`

```
index = sample(1:nrow(College), size=0.5*nrow(College))
train_2 = College[index,]
test_2  = College[-index,]
```

I now have two training & test sets, which is obviously not ideal. Is there a way I could only create one training/test set that can work with both `regsubsets` and `ridge/lasso`?

Thanks

Comment: What is `regsubsets`? (Perhaps from the `ISLR` package?) How are you calling it? How are you calling the other functions, `ridge` and `lasso`? Realize that we don't see your console, aren't familiar with your work/studies, and have only your words here to guide us to help you.

Comment: Hi, will make edit to my posts now.

Comment: Everywhere else you reference `College[train,]`, why not `regsubsets(Apps ~ ., data = College[train,])`?

Comment: I agree with @r2evans. It seems that `train` is a logical vector and not a `data.frame`. It should fail if `train` is logical vector if you e.g., pass it to `glm` or `lm`.